# Non-commutative algebra $A$ with a non-trivial maximal ideal $M$ such that $A/M$ is not a division algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples, noncommutative-algebra, algebras

By "ideal", I mean "two-sided ideal".

I'm looking for an example of a real/complex algebra $A$ which is non-commutative and has some maximal ideal $M$ with $\{0\}\subsetneq M\subsetneq A$ and $A/M$ is not a division algebra.

The counterexamples for

$$
M \text{ maximal ideal}\implies A/M \text{ division algebra}
$$

that I know of are $\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ (with $\mathbb F$ some field) and the Weyl algebra, but both of these are simple rings.

Comment: Noncommutative algebra is pretty far from my wheelhouse, but I remember reading somewhere that $A/M$ is a division algebra if and only if $M$ is maximal as a left and right ideal separately, whereas we call $M$ "maximal" if it's maximal as a $2$-sided ideal. So to build some example of this phenomenon, you probably want to try and build a ring with a maximal $2$-sided ideal that's non-maximal when viewed as, say, a left ideal. Unfortunately, how you might go about doing that is beyond me.... (+1) and followed, though! Good luck ^_^

Comment: Hello: I know you specifically put the banach-algebra tag and mentioned that you thought of this question while studying ba arch algebras.  But in fact the question you ask seems to be completely independent of banach algebras and their theory and better asked without mentioning it, so I edited it.  If you really still want a blurb about banach algebras you can edit something specific back into the question but I advise against using the ad a tag since it will not assist searchability.  Thanks

Comment: $M$ is maximal if and only if $A/M$ is a simple algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In other words you are looking for a ring with unique maximum ideal that is not simple and not local.

Take any noncommutative simple ring $R$ that is not a division ring.    You said you knew a couple: you could take the two by two matrix ring over the reals or complex numbers.

Form the trivial extension $S=R\times R$ where the addition operation is coordinatewise and multiplication is $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,ad+bc)$.

Since $I=\{0\}\times R$ is a nonzero nilpotent ideal, $S$ is not simple.  Furthermore the maximal ideals of $S$ correspond to those of $S/I$ which is simple, so $I$ is the unique maximal ideal, but not the unique maximal right ideal (since $S/I$ lacks a unique maximal right ideal.)

Comment: One thing to distinguish this from the full linear ring given in the other example is that this one can be chosen to be finite dimensional over a field.

Answer (score 3):

Let $F$ be a field and let $V$ be a vector space over $F$ having a countable basis $\{e_0,e_1,\dots,e_n,\dotsc\}$.

Let $R$ be the endomorphism ring of $V$. Then this ring has a unique nontrivial two-sided ideal, namely the set $K$ of endomorphisms with finite rank (in other words, such that the image is finitely generated). That this is a two-sided ideal is easy to see.

Suppose that the ideal $I$ contains an endomorphism $f$ having infinite rank. Then we can select $\{e_{k_0},e_{k_1},\dotsc\}$ such that $\mathscr{B}=\{f(e_{k_0},f(e_{k_1}),\dotsc\}$ is a basis for the image of $f$. Extend it to a basis $\mathscr{B}\cup\mathscr{C}$ (disjoint union) of $V$.

Now consider $g\in R$ defined by $g(f(e_{k_i}))=e_i$ and $g(v)=0$ for $v\in\mathscr{C}$ and $h\in R$ defined by $h(e_i)=e_{k_i}$.

Then we have
$$
gfh(e_i)=gf(e_{k_i})=e_i
$$
so $gfh$ is the identity and $gfh\in I$ and $I=R$.

Thus $K$ is indeed a maximal two-sided ideal, but $R/K$ is not a division ring, because $R$ has proper left ideals that properly contain $K$ (find an example).

As an aside, if $V$ is a vector space of dimension $\beta$ (an infinite cardinal, choice assumed), the proper nonzero ideals of the endomorphism ring $R$ of $V$ are of the form
$$
K_\alpha=\{f\in R:\dim\operatorname{im}f<\alpha\}
$$
where $\alpha$ runs through the infinite cardinals less than or equal to $\beta$. So we have several other examples, because the same idea as before shows that $K_\beta$ is the unique maximal two-sided ideal, but the quotient ring is not a division ring.

Comment: +1 This is a good example I should have remembered to include!  In fact, the ideals of the full linear ring over any vector space are linearly ordered. (You probably already know that but I include it for other readers.)

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, and they're indexed by the infinite cardinals less than the dimension. I added a comment. Of course your example is simpler and effective.